# PHP Math function returns wrong result

Tags: php, math

I have a variable containing:

```
40 * ($plvl^2)) + (360 * $plvl);
```

Where $plvl equals 2. According to wolfram and google the correct result is supposed to be 880 but the PHP function returns 720.

Does anyone know why they return different values and how do I correct it to result in 880?

Comment: I _constantly_ forget that `^` doesn't do what I think it does in PHP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$plvl^2
```

just inverts the second-lowest bit of plvl (`^` is the [bitwise XOR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)). You want [`pow`](http://php.net/pow):

```
40 * pow($plvl, 2) + 360 * $plvl;
```

Answer (score 5):

The `^` operator is not exponentiation, it is the eXclusive OR (XOR) bitwise operator.  Instead of `$plvl^2`, use `pow($plvl, 2)`

Answer (score 4):

`^` is XOR, not exponentiation.  2^2 is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Just :

```
$plvl = 2;

echo 40*$plvl*$plvl+360*$plvl; //880
```

Not need the parentheses actually.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
40 * pow($plvl,2) + (360 * $plvl);
```

it works then. Maybe, the ^ operator is not a valid php operator.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers: usually simple multiplication is way more efficient than using `pow`. So you should perhaps use `$plvl * $plvl` instead of `pow($plvl,2)`.